# Complex urn problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The urn contains 5 balls numbered $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$. We take a ball from the urn, write down its number and put it back into the urn. We repeat this action until the balls with numbers $1, 2, 3$ are drawn at least once. Calculate the probability that we repeat the operation $5$ times.

I would appreciate any hint for this exercise. I'm stuck with this one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you know the in-and-out formula?

Comment: @bof Do you mean the inclusion exclusion formula?

Comment: @callculus That's a pretty fancy name for it.

Comment: Clarification requested: "Calculate the probability that we repeat the operation 5 times."  Do you intend **at least** 5 times, or **exactly** 5 times?

Comment: Inclusion-Exclusion is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @bof That I was thinking. But I have never heard of it and I haven´t got many results in google. I don´t think that in-and-out formula is a commonly used expression.

Comment: For this exercise it's exactly 5 times and yes I know in-and-out formula, but I don't know how to use it in this example. I wanted to use here a Bernoulli's trail or binomial distribution somehow. Is it a good idea?

Comment: You know that there are $5^5$ total sequences, so the question reduces to enumerating the number of satisfying sequences.  Since you stop immediately after the $5$-th ball, the $5$-th ball must be one of $1,2,3$ such that the particular number is absent from the 1st $4$ balls.  This means that the problem is reduced to enumerating how many $4$ number sequences there are where two of the three numbers are there, but the 3rd number is missing. Then, the question reduces to identifying all the possible distribution patterns among the $4$ rolls.  ...see next comment

Comment: The possible distribution patterns are $aaab$, $aabb$, $aabc$ and $abcd$.  Here, each of the letters $a,b,c,d$ refers to a different number.  The distribution pattern refers to how many you have of each of the numbers present, but **does not** refer to the order that the numbers were drawn in.  Since you are using $5^5$ as a *denominator*, when enumerating the numerator, you must be consistent - that is, you must regard order that the balls are drawn in, as important.  This applies to each of the distribution patterns that refer to a *satisfying* way that the first $4$ balls might be drawn.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you very much for this explanation! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that we order the balls according to their selection order in a straight line . So , it become similar to obtaining $5$ digits numbers such that $[0,3,3,1,2] , [2,3,4,4,4]$ etc.

Because of the repetition allowed . The denominator will be $5^5$. It can be thought like how many $5$ digits number there are by using $(0,1,2,3,4)$ when repetition allowed . (and the first digit can be zero.)

Now , we should calculate that the number of events ($5$ digits number) when $1,2,3$ is used at least once. I can do it by inclusion -exclusion formula as you mentioned in comments. However , i want to give you much more easy and elegant way. It is called exponential generating functions.

By the reminder of OP , we know that the last digit must be $1,2,3$ to end the game. For now, lets assume that the last digit is $1$.

If $2,3$ is used at least once , their generating functions will be $x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} $.

If $0,4$ is used without restriction , their generating functions will be $1+x + \frac{x^2}{2}  $.

Then ,we should find the coefficient of the term $\frac{x^4}{4!}$ or find the coefficient of $x^4$ and multiply it by $4!$ in the expansion of these generating fuctions such that $(x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6})^2 \times  (1+x + \frac{x^2}{2})^2  $.

Then , https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2Bx%2B+x%5E2+%2F+2+%29%5E2+%28x+%2B+x%5E2+%2F+2+%2Bx%5E3%2F+6+%29%5E2+

$\color{red}{NOTE=}$ Do not forget that , we assume that $1$ is in the fifth digit , because if it were in some of preceding digit , the game will end uo without coming the fifth.This part was important to understand why we took the generating functions of the digits which appear at least once as $(x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6})^{\color{red}{2}} $ instead of $(x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6})^{\color{blue}{3}} $

We found that the coefficient of $x^4 = 110 $ by $\frac{55}{12} \times 4! =110$

However , there are $3$ possible end for our question such as $1,2,3$ . Hence we should multiply it by $3$ such that $3 \times 110 =330$

We found that the numerator will be $330$ and denominator $3125$ , so  answer is $0.1056  $

$\color{red}{NOTE=}$ I did not prefer bernoulli trial because it will be a little cumbersome . Moreover , i wanted to give you more powerful tool that you can use it more complex problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It helped me a lot, but I have possible a,b,c,d,e answers for this exercise. They look like this: A) 146/3125 B) 312/3125 C) 438/3125 D) 330/3125 E)110/3125

Comment: @DJcarlo what is answer ?

Comment: They look like this: A) 146/3125 B) 312/3125 C) 438/3125 D) 330/3125 E)110/3125. Sorry missclick

Comment: I tried to figure it out combinatorial way, but my results don't match too

Comment: If we want to repeat the operation 5 times, the last number we will write down must be 1, 2 or 3. So we have another 4 places before to think about. We choose 2 places for other two numbers from 1 2 3, so that gives us 4!/2!(4-2)!. We can permute the places for those numbers, so we multiply by 3!. On the two places that's left we can put some numbers from 0 to 4 but not the one that we placed on the last place in the beginning. So we multiply by 4 and again by 4 and that gives us the numerator equal to 576.

Comment: @DJcarlo oh i see my mistake , let me edit it

Comment: @DJcarlo it is done , i hope that the answer helped you

Comment: I'm very grateful for your solution and I think it's a correct answer, but I have a last question for you. Could you please explain to me how to use inclusion-exclusion formula here?

Comment: @DJcarlo my dear friend user2661923 gave it in comments above

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that. Now I understand everything. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Is this really much more easy and elegant than $3\left(4^4-3^4-3^4+2^4\right)$?

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities for which number comes up on the fifth draw: $1$, $2$, or $3$. Let's suppose $3$ comes up last.

Now the result of the first four draws is a string of length $4$ from the set $\{0,1,2,4\}$ in which neither $1$ nor $2$ is missing. By the in-and-out formula (sometimes grandiloquently called the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion) this is the total number of strings ($4^4$) minus the number with $1$ missing ($3^4$) minus the number with $2$ missing (also $3^4$) plus the number with both $1$ and $2$ missing ($2^4$). Finally we multiply by $3$ because the last number drawn could be $1$ or $2$ instead of $3$. So the numerator for your probability is
$$3\left(4^4-3^4-3^4+2^4\right)=330.$$